# How to minimize setup cost in linear programming model using R

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming

Suppose we have a matrix m:

```
> m
   C1 C2
M1 70 80
M2 50 61
M3 45 40
```

with machines M1-M3 and customers C1-C2. The values indicated the product volume that each machine could produce for a specific customer, e.g. if M1 was used, it would produce 70 items for C1 and 80 for C2.

I would like to minimize only the setup costs of all machines required to satisfy the demand using the following constraints:

Demand per customer >= 120; setup cost per machine = 1 if used for any customer, 0 otherwise.

For this simple example, the solution would be to use machines M1 and M2 (producing 120 for C1 and 141 for C2) resulting in total setup costs of 2. The only other feasible option is to use machines M1, M2, and M3 but that would result in setup costs of 3 and hence is not optimal.

How could this be solved using R? I looked at some examples using `lpSolve` but I struggle with modelling the setup cost so that they are 1 if anything is produced from a machine or 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Read chapter 6 of [MOSEK modeling manual](http://docs.mosek.com/generic/modeling-letter.pdf)http://docs.mosek.com/generic/modeling-letter.pdf , in particular, section 6.2, and example 6.1 in there.  That tells you exactly how to model your situation using binary variables. Then implement that approach in lpsolve, which allows the binary variables you need.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to create a binary variable for each Machine's setup cost. (It is an indicator variable.)

#### In English

If Machine 2 produces anything, then the binary variable `setup_2` = 1

If Machine 2 produces nothing, then `setup_2` = 0

We need one such binary variable for each machine.

#### Setup Constraint (Formulation)

Let BigM be a large number.
  Let `X_mj` be the number of jobs that machine m performs for customer j.

```
Sum(over all jobs) X_machine_job - BigM * setup_machine <= 0
```

If any of the `X_mj` variables is non-zero, that forces the `setup_machine` variable to become 1, which is what we want.

That's the only trick. The rest of the formulation is routine.
Here's your full example using `lpSolveAPI.`

#### R Code

(Code not optimized. Written so that it is easier to understand.)

```
library(lpSolveAPI)
lpAssign <- make.lp(ncol=9) #3 columns for SETUP variable (Binary) + 6 columns: 3 machines * 2 customers
#The first 3 columns are the setup variables (binary)
set.type(lpAssign, c(1,2,3), "binary")
add.constraint(lpAssign, c(1,1,1), type=">=", rhs=120, indices=c(4,6,8)) #meet demand for customer 1
add.constraint(lpAssign, c(1,1,1), type=">=", rhs=120, indices=c(5,7,9))

#capacity constraints (6 of them)
add.constraint(lpAssign, 1, type="<=", rhs=70, indices=c(4))
add.constraint(lpAssign, 1, type="<=", rhs=80, indices=c(5))
add.constraint(lpAssign, 1, type="<=", rhs=50, indices=c(6))
add.constraint(lpAssign, 1, type="<=", rhs=61, indices=c(7))
add.constraint(lpAssign, 1, type="<=", rhs=45, indices=c(8))
add.constraint(lpAssign, 1, type="<=", rhs=40, indices=c(9))

#setup cost variable constraint for each machine 
BigM <- 1e6
add.constraint(lpAssign, c(-1*BigM,1,1), type="<=", rhs=0, indices=c(1,4,5))
add.constraint(lpAssign, c(-1*BigM,1,1), type="<=", rhs=0, indices=c(2,6,7))
add.constraint(lpAssign, c(-1*BigM,1,1), type="<=", rhs=0, indices=c(3,8,9))

set.objfn(lpAssign, c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)) #All we care about is SET UP cost minimization

write.lp(lpAssign, "MinSetupLp.lp", "lp")#write it out
```

#### verify

```
> solve(lpAssign)
[1] 0
> sol <- get.variables(lpAssign)
> sol
[1]  1  1  0 70 80 50 40  0  0
> get.objective(lpAssign)
[1] 2
```

Comment: out of curiosity, what is that first line of code you posted doing?  I'm not much of an R ninja but I've never seen anything like it---a function call with an argument with spaces in it, followed by an expression, all evaluated as a boolean?  Or is that meant to be pseudo-code?

Comment: @Paul I think that's nearer to a mathematical expression but one could easily interpret it as pseuco-code. I really don't think it's intended to be R code.